# Export text to csv using first and last column

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I get a statement like this in text format every month.
I can not import it in a spreadsheet easily.

```
28/03/2023 NETBANKING TRANSFER (Ref# 328012838897) 7,465.00 Cr
29/03/2023 BHAVNA CHEMIST 848.00
29/03/2023 ANUPAM STATIONERY MUMBAI 199.00
04/04/2023 SpayBBPS 2100001818 Mahan 30933624 1,134.00
```

The first column is date, the last (in some cases second last) column is amount.
The middle part is "description"

```
28/03/2023 | NETBANKING TRANSFER (Ref# 328012838897) | 7,465.00  | Cr
29/03/2023 | BHAVNA CHEMIST  |  848.00  | 
29/03/2023 | ANUPAM STATIONERY MUMBAI | 199.00  | 
04/04/2023 | SpayBBPS 2100001818 Mahan 30933624 | 1,134.00  |
```

Is there any way to export it to csv?

I tried this command:

```
awk '{print $1 " | some magic | "  $NF}' test.txt
```

How to replace the "some magic" to the real code? I am OK if 'Cr' appear in the last column, I can change that manually.

I can get the second column using cut like this...

```
cat test.txt | cut -d ' ' -f2- | rev | cut -d ' ' -f2- | rev
```

But I am not sure how to format it with first and last column.

Comment: With the three character delimiter of `' | '` you don't *really* have a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/( .*)( [0-9,.]+) ?/ |\1 |\2 | /' file
```

Using greed: place 3 `|` delimiters (with spaces either side),  replacing the first space, the one before the last number and following the last number.

Comment: elegant and readable. Upvoted and accepted.

Comment: I am getting the same results if I remove space and question mark ' ?' Is it OK or it's required?

Comment: @shantanuo just `belt n'braces` in case the number is the very last field on a line.

Answer (score 2):

Anything with PCRE allows this parsing.

The regex:

```
/^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)\s+(.*?)\s+([\d,]+\.\d\d) *(.*)$/
```

Separates out the four groups. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VwwbMG/1)

Here is a Ruby using that regex:

```
ruby  -e '$<.each{|line|
    puts line.scan(/^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)\s+(.*?)\s+([\d,]+\.\d\d) *(.*)$/).join(" | ") }
' file
```

Or Perl:

```
perl -nE 'say join(" | ", $1, $2, $3, $4) 
           if m/^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)\s+(.*?)\s+([\d,]+\.\d\d) *(.*)$/' file
```

You can also do in two steps with `sed` as long as the version supports `{repetitions}` which most modern versions do:

```
sed -E 's/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4} /&| /; s/(.*) ([0-9,]{1,}\.[0-9]{2})(.*)$/\1 | \2 | \3/' file
```

Any of those prints:

```
28/03/2023 | NETBANKING TRANSFER (Ref# 328012838897) | 7,465.00 | Cr
29/03/2023 | BHAVNA CHEMIST | 848.00 | 
29/03/2023 | ANUPAM STATIONERY MUMBAI | 199.00 | 
04/04/2023 | SpayBBPS 2100001818 Mahan 30933624 | 1,134.00 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Assummptions:

- desired output should always have 1 space before/after the `|` (unlike in OP's sample output which varies between 1 and 2 spaces)
- if a line has an optional 4th field (eg, `Cr` in the example), this 4th field never contains a number
- if a line does not have an optional 4th field we end the line with `|` (no trailing white space)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
      { $1=$1 " |"                     # append " |" to 1st field
        if ($NF ~ /[0-9]/)             # if last field is a monetary value (ie, no 4th field)
           $NF="| " $NF " |"           # prepend with "| " and end line with "|" (sans trailing white space)
        else {                         # else prepend last two fields with "| "
           $(NF-1)="| " $(NF-1)
           $NF="| " $NF
        }
      }
1                                      # print modified line to stdout
' test.txt
```

This generates:

```
28/03/2023 | NETBANKING TRANSFER (Ref# 328012838897) | 7,465.00 | Cr
29/03/2023 | BHAVNA CHEMIST | 848.00 |
29/03/2023 | ANUPAM STATIONERY MUMBAI | 199.00 |
04/04/2023 | SpayBBPS 2100001818 Mahan 30933624 | 1,134.00 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's~[0-9/]+~& |~;s~([0-9]+,)?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+~| & |~' input_file
28/03/2023 | NETBANKING TRANSFER (Ref# 328012838897) | 7,465.00 | Cr
29/03/2023 | BHAVNA CHEMIST | 848.00 |
29/03/2023 | ANUPAM STATIONERY MUMBAI | 199.00 |
04/04/2023 | SpayBBPS 2100001818 Mahan 30933624 | 1,134.00 |
```

Comment: Some explanation of this magic will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
28/03/2023 NETBANKING TRANSFER (Ref# 328012838897) 7,465.00 Cr
29/03/2023 BHAVNA CHEMIST 848.00
29/03/2023 ANUPAM STATIONERY MUMBAI 199.00
04/04/2023 SpayBBPS 2100001818 Mahan 30933624 1,134.00
```

then

```
awk '{$1=$1 " |";if($NF+0){$NF="| " $NF}else{$(NF-1)="| " $(NF-1)};print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
28/03/2023 | NETBANKING TRANSFER (Ref# 328012838897) | 7,465.00 Cr
29/03/2023 | BHAVNA CHEMIST | 848.00
29/03/2023 | ANUPAM STATIONERY MUMBAI | 199.00
04/04/2023 | SpayBBPS 2100001818 Mahan 30933624 | 1,134.00
```

Explanation: I append space followed by pipe symbol to first field to shear 1st field from rest, then I check if last file has prefix which constitutes non-zero number, if it does hold I prepend pipe followed by space to last field otherwise I prepend that to field before last one. **Disclaimer** I assume your input data has always 3 or more fields, if that does not hold do not use my code.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Your first line is supposed to separate out the `Cr` as a forth field with the remaining having an empty field, no?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really do want a valid CSV output then, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\",\"" }
match($0,/^(\S+)\s+(.*\S)\s+([0-9][0-9,.]*)\s*(\S+)?$/,a) {
    print "\"" a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4] "\""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
"28/03/2023","NETBANKING TRANSFER (Ref# 328012838897)","7,465.00","Cr"
"29/03/2023","BHAVNA CHEMIST","848.00",""
"29/03/2023","ANUPAM STATIONERY MUMBAI","199.00",""
"04/04/2023","SpayBBPS 2100001818 Mahan 30933624","1,134.00",""
```

If your input lines can contain double quotes then add this immediately before the `print` line to escape them in the output:

```
    for ( i=1; i in a; i++ ) {
        gsub(/"/,"\"\"",a[i])
    }
```